# Json String to Java Object with dynamic key name

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to parse this structured of json string to Java Object but I failed every attempt.

```
{
  "message": "Test Message",
  "status": true,
  "users": {
    "user_xy": [
      {
        "time": "2016-08-25 19:01:20.944614158 +0300 EEST",
        "age": 24,
        "props": {
          "pr1": 197,
          "pr2": 0.75,
          "pr3": 0.14,
          "pr4": -0.97
        }
      }
    ],
    "user_zt": [
      {
        "time": "2016-08-25 17:08:36.920891187 +0300 EEST",
        "age": 29,
        "props": {
          "pr1": 1.2332131860505051,
          "pr2": -0.6628148829634317,
          "pr3": -0.11622442112006928
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

props field can contain 1 properties or 6 properties, it depends on db record. Also Username part dynamically changing.

Can I parse successfully this structured string with Jackson Lib?

Comment: Parse users as a JSONArray and iterate ! Parsing props in the same way should work too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to create calss structure like bellow to map your string to java object.

Create one class for Details

```
public class Details {
    private String message;
    private String status;
    private Map<String, List<UserDetails>> users = new HashMap<String, List<UserDetails>>();
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public Map<String, List<UserDetails>> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    public void setUsers(Map<String, List<UserDetails>> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

Create UserDetails class like bellow.

```
public class UserDetails {
    private String time;
    private String age;
    private Map<String, String> prop = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public Map<String, String> getProp() {
        return prop;
    }
    public void setProp(Map<String, String> prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }   
}
```

Now you can map your string with Details class.

Hope this will help..

Comment: Thank you, thats really helped. But I use
`Map<String, UserInfo[]>`
instead of 
`Map<String, List<UserDetails>>`

Comment: Hey, what if the keys of userDerails are dynamic, how can I map them

Comment: thank you for such a simple explanation and example, saved my day. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```html
 public class Details  {
 private String message;
 private boolean status;
 Users UsersObject;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String getMessage() {
  return message;
 }

 public boolean getStatus() {
  return status;
 }

 public Users getUsers() {
  return UsersObject;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setMessage(String message) {
  this.message = message;
 }

 public void setStatus(boolean status) {
  this.status = status;
 }

 public void setUsers(Users usersObject) {
  this.UsersObject = usersObject;
 }
}
public class Users {
 ArrayList < Object > user_xy = new ArrayList < Object > ();
 ArrayList < Object > user_zt = new ArrayList < Object > ();


 // Getter Methods 



 // Setter Methods 


}
```

You can also use online JSON to JAVA Object Converter : https://codebeautify.org/json-to-java-converter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).