# how to map dynamic key in a json node to a class?

Tags: java, json, objectmapper, jsonparser

I have a json like this,I have used to map this to a class using object mapper,where I have considered **auth** as JsonNode in the class UserData.java

```
    {
  "auth": [
    {
      "user_admin": [
        {
          "name": [
            "harry"
          ],
          "department": [
            "MC"
          ],
          "userid": [
            "1234"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "user_employee": [
        {
          "name": [
            "stella"
          ],
          "department": [
            "CC"
          ],
          "role": [
            "employee"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "language":"english",
  "sub": "f598ab"

}
```

I have used json node for **auth** to map it to a class UserData.java as below.

```
 @Getter@Setter
    private JsonNode authorization;
    @Getter@Setter
    private String language;
     @Getter@Setter
    private String sub;
```

Now I want to map the values user_admin and user_employee which are dynamic to another class which will have name,department,userid. I have created a class auth.java and put this code in it.

```
 @Getter    @Setter
        private List< String> name;

        @Getter @Setter
        private List<String> department;

        @Getter @Setter
        private List<String> userid;
       @Getter  @Setter
       private List<String> role;
```

now I have tried the below code to map it,but its not working I am getting

```
UserData mappedObject=  (UserData)commonUtils.readJsonStringRespondToObjRequest((json), UserData.class);
Auth roleData=  mapper.treeToValue(mappedObject.getAuth(), Auth.class);
```

Error I got is

```
Can not deserialize instance of Auth.java out of START_ARRAY
```

Comment: Try deserializing to an array of Auth instead of a single Auth object.

Comment: how to do that ? @alayor

Answer (score 0):

Given that your JSON structure `auth` is an `array` you need to convert that into an array of `Auth` objects.

```
Auth[] roleData = mapper.treeToValue(mappedObject.getAuth(), Auth[].class);
```

Also, in your `Auth` class you should have these properties.

```
class Auth {
   @Getter @Setter
   UserAdmin user_admin;
   @Getter @Setter
   UserEmployee user_employee;
   @Getter @Setter
   String language;
   @Getter @Setter
   String sub;
}
```

Then, in `UserAdmin` and `UserEmployee`, you should have the fields corresponding to each property in JSON (name, department, etc).

Comment: Its giving me unexpected field user_admin since  user_admin   and user_employee are dynamic @alayor

Comment: The error is because `Auth` class doesn't have `user_admin` and `user_employee` fields.

Comment: those values are dynamic,and changes from response to response,How to get hold of them,Thats where I am stuck from a long time,please help me with this @alayor

Comment: Is there any approach to get hold of dynamic values of  user_admin,user_employee @alayor

Comment: I think you need to explain what `dynamic` means in your case. If the name of the properties changes or what are those changes.

Comment: the key names user_employee,user_admin changes,say there might be another response with user_supplier @alayor

Comment: In this case, the JSON response is not well structured. Do you own the code that sends the JSON response? If you do, you should add a property indicating the user type (employee, admin, supplier) and remove the dynamic names.

Comment: No I dont own it.I was going through this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159770/json-string-to-java-object-with-dynamic-key-name),It worked for them,Its  not working for me,can you tell me what I am missing ? @alayor